# Weblogic Adapter in Eclipse Neon missing

Tags: weblogic, eclipse-neon

I have installed Weblogic 12.2.1 using the following tutorial successfully on my Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

I am now trying to configure weblogic in my Eclipse Neon. I am not able to see any server adapters that others see in different tutorials.

After some reading online I installed OEP 12.2.1.6 software  and restarted eclipse but it of no help

[LIST OF SERVERS ADAPTERS I SEE IN TUTORIALS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J99Vl.png)

[LIST I AM SEEING AFTER INSTALLING OEPE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjN1Q.png)

I need those adapters to add weblogic to my eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question some days ago after checking some online tutorials.

In the later versions of OEPE, you only see a "unified" oracle weblogic server adapter.

Once you have selected this option, you will be able to choose the desired server runtime environment from a list of the runtimes configured on your machine (separate download).

If you see none, then you will have to configure some before trying to add a weblogic server.

[image: My configured weblogic server runtimes]